# How to register a widget in WordPress Genesis child theme?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I'm attempting to register a new widget area in my Genesis child theme for WordPress. The code doesn't seem to be working and crashes my site. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to get it above the content on all pages. This is the code I have:

```
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => ‘above_content’,
    'name'        => __( ‘Above Content’, 'domain' ),
    'description' => __( ‘Above the content’, 'domain' ),
));

add_action( 'genesis_before_loop’, ‘above_content’ );
function your_widget() {
if ( is_active_sidebar(‘above_content’) ) {
    genesis_widget_area( ‘above_content’, array(
     'before' => '<div class=“above_content widget-area">',
     'after'     => '</div>',
   )); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Also, make sure you're using standard single quotes `'`, not curly quotes `’`

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize there were different types of quotes. Thanks for pointing that out! I fixed the quotes and now the widget shows in my admin area but it isn't showing on the site.

Comment: The code is in my functions file

Comment: I believe you need to change the `above_content` callback to `your_widget`. In other words: `add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'your_widget' );`

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much! I'm curious though, should the id be changed too? And what happens if I register another widget? It can't be your_widget also, can it? Sorry, this is all very new to me!

Comment: You'll need to use a unique ID. Check out my answer for a bit more info, and feel free to post a new question if you have trouble getting two widgets to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure you're using standard quotes `'`, not curly quotes `‘`
2. Assign the proper callback to your action

```
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'above_content',
    'name'        => __( 'Above Content', 'domain' ),
    'description' => __( 'Above the content', 'domain' ),
) );

add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'your_widget' );
function your_widget() {
    if ( is_active_sidebar('above_content') ) {
        genesis_widget_area( 'above_content', array(
           'before' => '<div class="above_content widget-area">',
           'after'  => '</div>',
        ) ); 
    }
}
```

If you want to register another widget, just register a new sidebar (with a unique ID), and add new logic to a new callback function (or add it to `your_widget()`). Where you add this additional widget depends on your specific use case.